# java \r character not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, loops, carriage-return

Please advise why this is not working, I am sure you can figure out what I am trying to do here:

```
            while (socketChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            fileChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
            bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(kilobyteDecimal);
            System.out.print("\\ \r"+"| \r"+"/ \r"+"-- \r");
        }
```

expecting to see rotating characters but instead I am getting a new line in every print statement.

Many Thanks

Comment: which kind of pattern you want to show ?

Comment: `\r` is the character for a return, you can try `\\r` to escape the `\\` but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JornVernee Hi, I am trying to mimic the old Sun Microsystem dial...

I tried using the \b also going back a character so that it looks like rotating on the stop \|/--

Comment: Where do you execute your program? In Eclipse/IDE or in a terminal/console?

Comment: @Robert, I've tried both in Eclipse and on console and the result is always the same.

Comment: Currently noticed that if I remove \r it stays on the same line (great) but I now have a issue adding \b for backspace so that it returns to the start of the line to print out the next character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do what I wanted, although the code has to change a bit this is exactly what i wanted and it works as expected:

```
public class ProgressDial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    if (args[0].equals("false")) {
        System.out.println("Args = false");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        while (args[0].equals("true")) {
            System.out.print("\\");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\b ");
            System.out.print("\r");
            System.out.print("|");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\b ");
            System.out.print("\r");
            System.out.print("/");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\b ");
            System.out.print("\r");
            System.out.print("-");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\b ");
            System.out.print("\r");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks to everyone that give me advice and ideas.

Comment: It works for me without the carriage return